# How to test a variable assignment within a method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Say I have method that just appends a string to an input string..

```
def request(
    url: str,
    headers: dict = None
):
    default_headers = {
        "user-agent": "some user agent"
    }
    
    if isinstance(headers, dict):
        default_headers.update(headers)
```

When I run a coverage report for this method, it says that `default_headers.update(headers)` needs coverage. How do I add coverage for this statement?

Comment: Why are you splitting apart your string and then putting it together again? `''.join([char for char in 'test'])` is the same thing as `'test'`. Also, you're using PEP 484 type hints, so I assume you're using `mypy` or some other type checker. That means you needn't be testing the return types of functions, since your type checker is doing that for you already. You should be testing that the *values* are correct.

Comment: probably something about the looping constructs -- like maybe an empty array will cover it

Comment: @SilvioMayolo point taken - i updated my question with an example method closer to my scenario..

Comment: You can create a test case in which you pass headers(as dict) unless you haven't already being doing that(asking as we dont see any test case here).

Answer (score 1):

Coverage counts lines which are actually encountered during execution in tests. So in your case, if that line is not being covered, it is because the conditional:

```py
if isinstance(headers, dict):
```

must never evaluate to true in your test cases. To gain coverage for this line, pass a keyword argument `headers` as a dict.

A good discussion of statement coverage testing and its limitations can be found in this post: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/flaws_in_coverage_measurement.html